# best mobile processor for j2ee programming

Tags: jakarta-ee

hello i'm a j2ee programming i want buy a new  dell workstation but I am confused as to

Processeur Intel® Core i7-6920HQ (quatre coeurs, 2,9 GHz, 3,8 GHz Turbo, 8 Mo, 45 W, carte graphique Intel HD 530) 
    and

Processeur Intel® Xeon® E3-1545M v5 (quatre coeurs, 2,9 GHz, 3,8 GHz Turbo, 8 Mo, 45 W, carte graphique Iris Pro P580)

Comment: Why are you confuse?? What do you expect from the equipment that you want to buy ?

Comment: i want  know who is the best professeur for j2ee programming

Comment: Both are very similar (I even will say that they're equals) ... for j2ee programming, both will be fine ... see specs: [Xeon](http://ark.intel.com/products/93359/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1545M-v5-8M-Cache-2_90-GHz) and [i7](http://ark.intel.com/products/88972/Intel-Core-i7-6920HQ-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz)